# Javascript Forloop, insert new line at certain lenght

Tags: javascript

How do I create a `javascript forloop` which takes the input as a regular string, but insert `\n` at a fixed interval?

For instance, if this is the input:

Input:

```
x="This is a new line.This is a new line.This is a new line.This is a new line.This is a new line."
```

Lets say the interval is set to `19`

The loop will insert a `\n` at the end of 19 characters for the entire string

```
x="This is a new line.**\n**This is a new line.**\n**This is a new line.**\n**This is a new line.**\n**This is a new line."
```

And thereby producing the output if we were to do `alert(x)`

```
This is a new line.
This is a new line.
This is a new line.
This is a new line.
This is a new line.
```

I have tried several fiddles, but none are anywhere substantial to a suitable result.

Similar questions that don't quite answer my question:

[how to break line after certain length using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588856/how-to-break-line-after-certain-length-using-javascript)

[javascript code (new line, loops)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962639/javascript-code-new-line-loops)

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your problem?

Comment: There is no `\n` in variable x so why is the output on multiple lines? Strictly speaking.

Comment: are you looking to break after a pre-defined number of characters, or at certain points e.g. at each full stop?

Comment: the question was edited for better understanding

Comment: please excuse the previous version of the quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = x="This is a new line.This is a new line.This is a new line.This is a new line.This is a new line."

var a = [];
var i = 12; // Every 12 characters


// Split the string into an array of 12 character strings
do {
    a.push(x.substring(0, i));
} while((x = x.substring(i, x.length)) != "");

// Join the strings
a = a.join('\n');

alert(a);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2phaszu/#&togetherjs=7r6LvTdD9R)